# What is "the line children draw to represent a bird in flight"?

Tags: meaning, cultural-context, neuromancer, william-gibson

> The expression on her face, then, had been the  one he'd seen,
> hours later, on her sleeping face in  a port side coffin, her upper lip like
> the line children draw to represent a bird in flight.

I'm reading *Neuromancer* and don't understand what "the line children draw to represent a bird in flight" is. Anyone familiar with the culture please explain to me.

Comment: [Here](https://www.cleanpng.com/png-bird-flight-gulls-drawing-birds-silhouette-2828071/) is a drawing that should give you some idea of what he means, although the drawing I've linked to is much too sophisticated. I think it means a line with a downward cusp in the middle.

Comment: @PeterShor, in some elementary school art curricula, the "two circle arcs joined at a cusp" is a standard lesson about formulaic drawing of birds. There's also an associated formulaic drawing of clouds, etc. :)  So, even if it's not natural, it is "standard". :)

Comment: @PeterShor I think it's quite common. An image search for [art children drawing scenery](https://www.google.com/search?q=art+children+drawing+scenery&tbm=isch) sometimes shows the mentioned bird drawing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It means this simple double curved line, which can be seen as the shape of an upper lip, or wings in flight.

[image: lip shaped birds or bird shaped lips?]